# How to check if navigateTo was called in nuxt.js

Tags: vue.js, jestjs, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3, vitest

I'm working on a Nuxt.js project and using Vitest for unit testing. I need to verify if the navigateTo function from Nuxt.js is called with a specific path in my tests.

Here's the relevant part of my component (Form.vue), where navigateTo is invoked:

```
// Form.vue

const onClick = () => {
    await navigateTo('/')
}
```

```
// Form.test.ts

const navigateToMock = vi.fn()

it('When submit clicked, Then make redirect', async () => {
  const wrapper = mount(...)

  await wrapper.find("[data-testid='login']").trigger('submit')
  await flushPromises()

  expect(navigateToMock).toHaveBeenCalledWith('/')
})
```

I'm struggling to figure out how to spy on or effectively test whether navigateTo was called or not. Does anyone have any suggestions or ideas on how to approach this?